# using dbf library in python Ñ replaced by ╤

Tags: python, dbf

so im using a dbf library to read a file

```
import dbf 
Db = dbf.Table ('sometable.dbf',codepage='cp437')
Db.open ()
for record in Db:
    print(record.somefield)
```

it totally works but im having trouble with certain characters for example all the ñ are being shown as ╤. how can i fix this ?

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that the table is coded in `cp437`? Your result is more consistent with [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1).

Comment: Why are you overriding the code page?  The correct code page *should* be in the table itself.

Comment: i dont know which code page to use, if i dont use any i get an error 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd1. ive recently found that it is indeed ISO-8859-1 how do i setup the table to use that ? edit: using Db.codepage gives me plain ol' ascii

Comment: @EdyGomez, I think is something with your environment, because I used your code in creating one template dbf table, and then I added char ñ in the field.  After that I readed the field and everything was like it was recorded, the char ñ was printed correctely.  I’m using here a Mac OS X  with pt br language.

Comment: @MarkRansom it was indeed the codepage changed it to cp1252 and now it's working fine. thanks for the help